# How to enable bluetooth from the command line for using the keyboard for another device

Tags: bluetooth, nmcli

I'd like to enable my bluetooth connection from the command line for external use on another device.
Although there's the manpage of nmcli with examples (`man nmcli-examples`), I couldn't make it to the point yet where I can successfully "register" (like my wifi network), enable or disable my bluetooth connection/hardware.
How to do this?

Comment: Presumably you're using some Linux distro? Have you tried `bluetoothctl`?

Comment: I do use `GNU/Linux`. I tried `bluetoothctl` right now, but for the first time, so unfamiliar with it.